# Binding RelayCommand don't want to execute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command, relaycommand

I have got `Page.xaml`

```
<Page>
  <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:ExcelViewModel />
  </Page.DataContext>

  <Grid>
     <Button Command="{Binding Path=CopyCommand}" Margin="5"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is my `ExcelViewModel.cs`

```
public ExcelViewModel()
{
  SourcePath = @"\\test\\2019";
}

private readonly IExcelService fileService;
public ICommand CopyCommand{ get; private set; }

public ExcelViewModel(IExcelService fileService)
{
 this.fileService = fileService;   
 CopyCommand= new RelayCommand(CopyExcel);
}
```

But when I tried to run "CopyExcel" nothing is happend.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating the `ExcelViewModel` class in the XAML using the default constructor. Your `CopyCommand` is only initialized in the second constructor with parameter.

Change it to this and it should work:

```
public ExcelViewModel()
{
    SourcePath = @"\\test\\2019";
    CopyCommand= new RelayCommand(CopyExcel);
}

private readonly IExcelService fileService;
public ICommand CopyCommand{ get; private set; }

public ExcelViewModel(IExcelService fileService)
{
    this.fileService = fileService;   
}
```

---

Update:

It is always a good idea to call the default constructor from any special constructors as Rand Random suggested.

This will not solve your problem (as your XAML view calls the default constructor)!
But for reference, it will look like this:

```
public ExcelViewModel()
{
    SourcePath = @"\\test\\2019";
    CopyCommand= new RelayCommand(CopyExcel);
}

private readonly IExcelService fileService;
public ICommand CopyCommand{ get; private set; }

public ExcelViewModel(IExcelService fileService) : this()
{
    this.fileService = fileService;   
}
```

Credits go to Rand Random.

Comment: Probably want to call the empty ctor when using the one with parameters. So this line `public ExcelViewModel(IExcelService fileService)` maybe should be `public ExcelViewModel(IExcelService fileService) : this()` - doesn't happen automatically as you can see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XIKqdZ

Comment: @Rand - should I add "this" to my second constructor? can you please write it as answer

Comment: @4est - answer got updated correclty, with the original answer you would have faced the same problem when you called the `constructor` with the parameter of `IExcelService fileService` since now you would't initialize the `CopyCommand` in said constructor but only in the empty one - so instead of fixing it for both constructor you only moved the problem from one to the other - by calling the `empty constructor` you initialize `CopyCommand` no matter what `constructor` you use

Comment: @Rand how can I then do it correctly? now the problem is into first or second ctor

Comment: @4est - as I said, the answer got an update - which does it correctly

Comment: To clarify: the first answer is correct for the requested use case as well. In the requested use case, the view model is instantiated in the view and this automatically calls the default constructor. As it is always a good idea to call the default constructor from all special constructors, I added this option as well. **But the special constructor is not used in this implementation, therefore it makes no difference!** If you need `IExcelService` in your view model, you have to get it from somewhere else (or instantiate the view model first and the view out of it).

Comment: this is fine, what I did is to also inject instance of class to first ctor and "CopyCommand" moved to second ctor, without this, and its working great, thank you so much for help guys!